# String tuple serializer

Tags: kotlin

Please review my class which is responsible of serialization and deserialization of the `StringTuple` data class.

```
data class StringTuple(
    val first: String,
    val second: String
)
```

The idea is to serialize `StringTuple` to `ByteArray` in the following format:

```
| first string size | first string serialized | second string serialized |
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.charset.Charset

private val charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")

class StringTupleSerializer {

    fun serialize(value: StringTuple): ByteArray {
        val first = value.first.toByteArray(charset)
        val firstSize = encodeSize(first.size)
        val second = value.second.toByteArray(charset)
        return firstSize + first + second
    }

    private fun encodeSize(size: Int): ByteArray {
        val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        buffer.putInt(0, size)
        return buffer.array()
    }

    fun deserialize(byteArray: ByteArray): StringTuple {
        val firstSize = decodeSize(byteArray)
        val withoutFirstSize = byteArray.drop(Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        val first = withoutFirstSize.take(firstSize).toByteArray().toString(charset)
        val second = withoutFirstSize.drop(firstSize).toByteArray().toString(charset)
        return StringTuple(first, second)
    }

    private fun decodeSize(byteArray: ByteArray): Int {
        val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        buffer.put(byteArray, 0, Int.SIZE_BYTES)
        buffer.flip()
        return buffer.int
    }
}
```

I'm looking mainly for the review of correctness of this solution.

Comment: If you're "looking mainly for the review of correctness of this solution." why don't you write some unit tests to check exactly what you want?!